# Change the UIButton title when click on UITableviewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton

I make simple player with VK Api. I want to do this.

> When I clicked first track and then second change first button title "stop" to "play" automatically.

How to do it?

My play/stop button action.

```
func playAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    if sender.currentTitle == "P" {
        let track = dataOfTracks[sender.tag] as trackDoc
        let url = NSURL(string: track.data.url)

        player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
        player.play()
        sender.setTitle("S", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else if sender.currentTitle == "S" {
        sender.setTitle("P", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        player.pause()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't understand what you want? Are you want to change title of the button when you clicked on any cell?Please elaborate more

Comment: @chiragshah when I click play in first cell with track and then second, I need change first cell button title to default("play")

Comment: for that you have to get that button from cell and change the title of that button. i do it objective c but not on swift

Comment: @chiragshah send me ojb-c code dr_temka@icloud.com

Comment: @chiragshah this is my problem right now. How can I do this in objective-c?

Comment: @user3423040 go through vijay yadav answer you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

EDIT CODE DETAILS:

1. don't reallocate every time the button. It must be another outlet of the SongsTableViewCell class (same as the label). And set the target/action from the Interface Builder (add @IBAction in front of "func cellSongClicked" and ctrl-drag from IB)

   2.add the following property to your class:`private var currentSong : Int?`
   3) method cellForRowAtIndexPath:

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   ```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SongTitleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SongsTableViewCell

   let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

   cell.lblSongTitle.text = songDic.objectForKey("SongTitle") as? String
   cell.btnPlayPause.tag = indexPath.row

   var title : String
   if let _currentSong = currentSong {
       title = indexPath.row == _currentSong ? "Stop" : "Play"
   } else {
       title = "Play"
   }
   cell.btnPlayPause.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

   return cell
   ```

   }

4) And the action:

```
@IBAction func cellSongClicked (sender : AnyObject ){
    var remote = GetSongData()
    remote.delegate = self

    var btnCurrentPressed = sender as UIButton

    //Play Selected Song
    let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(btnCurrentPressed.tag) as NSDictionary

    var rowsToReload = [NSIndexPath]()
    var stopCurrent = false
    if let _currentSong = currentSong {
        if btnCurrentPressed.tag == _currentSong {
            stopCurrent = true
        } else {
            rowsToReload.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: _currentSong, inSection:0))
        }
    }
    rowsToReload.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: btnCurrentPressed.tag, inSection:0))
    currentSong = stopCurrent ? nil : btnCurrentPressed.tag
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(rowsToReload, withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the title of the button every time. You could use something like this:

```
func viewDidLoad {
    playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    playButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Selected)
}
```

Then in your callback method you just change the state of the button and the text will get updated too:

```
func playAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    // Selected means the content is playing
    if !sender.selected {
        let track = dataOfTracks[sender.tag] as trackDoc
        let url = NSURL(string: track.data.url)

        player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
        player.play()
    } else {
        player.pause()
    }
    // update the state of the button
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

I consider this to be a more clean solution since you are not comparing strings anymore to make your decision and you are actually using the binary state of the button to keep track of the current state of your content(which is also binary, either playing or not).

If you have more questions, I would be more than happy to help you further, just let me know.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What does not work?

Comment: I added gif for my problem

Comment: How do you set the width of the button? It seems to be just a layout problem. Just increase the width so that Stop can also be displayed and it should work

Comment: Nonono. I need set title previous button to default when clicked next track